# Angular is always matching requests to the first defined route

Tags: angular

I have created a new Angular 10 app and created two routes. However, it seems that Angular is matching every request to the first route and I can't figure out why. If I create just a single '/login' route and try to access it in my browser, then Angular isn't picking it up either. It seems like Angular isn't able to map router correctly?

Here's my app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    LoginModule,
    SignupModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: AuthenticationService, useClass: AuthenticationImpService},
    {provide: SignupService, useClass: SignupImpService},
    {provide: ToastService, useClass: ToastService}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then here is the AppRoutingModule;

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: CommunitiesComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding patchMatch: 'full':

```
  {path: '', component: CommunitiesComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }.
```

**Explanation:**

patchMatch: 'full' means that the whole URL path needs to match in order for the route to load. The default pathMatch is 'prefix', which means that the router will match the route when the URL begins with the prefix path. This is why it probably loads the first component the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding patchMatch: 'full':

```
  {path: '', component: CommunitiesComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }.
```

**Explanation:**

patchMatch: 'full' means that the whole URL path needs to match in order for the route to load. The default pathMatch is 'prefix', which means that the router will match the route when the URL begins with the prefix path. This is why it probably loads the first component the entire time.

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't work. I've gone ahead and created a brand new product with two components, and routing works fine on that, so I think it must be something to do with the way I have my app configured. I'm just going to move everything across to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed redirectTo:

```
{pathMatch: 'full', path: '', redirectTo: 'login'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'
},{
  path:'login',component:LoginComponent
},{
  path:'**', redirectTo: 'login'
}];
```

Try this way.

Below is the explanation for the code :

1. The path redirects the empty url to your login page ie. you can see url change to "/login" .
2. The path redirects to login page if there is "/login" in your url.
3. If the user enters invalid url, it will be redirected to login page ie. you can see url change to "/login" .

Happy coding!

Edit 1: Also try giving a path for your CommunitiesComponent as you have done for LoginComponent , which can make your code more simpler and easy to manage .

Answer (score 0):

As @yair cohen told use  **pathMatch: 'full'** while declaring route.
an other thing is to order them from more to less specific.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component: CommunitiesComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
  
];
```